# Flow after RPC call in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

```
public Class GUi(){
 // More Code

public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

LoginServer loginServer =new  LoginServer(getTextBoxUsername().getText(),getTextBoxPassword().getText());     
loginServer.setConnection(connection);
connection=loginServer.getConnection();
System.out.println(" connected "+connection);
// More code
}

public class LoginServer {
// more code
public void setConnection(Boolean connection) {

    String[] authentication = {username,password};
    //RPC call
    connectionService.connectionServer(authentication, callbackConnection); 
    System.out.println("setConnection" + connection);
}

public Boolean getConnection() {
    return connection;
}
AsyncCallback callbackConnection = new AsyncCallback() {

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connection=false;
    }

    public void onSuccess(Object result) {
        connection=true;
        System.out.println("onSuccess + connection);

    }
};

}
```

Output

```
setConnectionnull
connected null
onSuccesstrue
```

According to Me the Output should be.

```
 onSuccesstrue
 setConnectiontrue
 connected null
```

Because I made object of `LoginServer ;` Then I call method `setConnection` where there is RPC call written which is working perfectly fine.
`OnSucces` will change the value of connection.
 Then I called method `getConnection` .

I also don't understand why `connected null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When/if you ask your wife/girlfriend to bring you a beer, you don't have that beer in your hand the second after you asked her, and you can continue watching the match and reacting, you're not blocked waiting for your beer: that's called asynchronous processing.

Similarly, `connection` is still `null` the second after you send your RPC call.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/Google-Web-Toolkit/-soVdfMGug8/vRmqIcAZ5zsJ

Comment: :) Nice explaination. The above link is not a good link. I mean the page is not opening.
Can you suggest me some method whic can be used to wait for asyncCall to complete and then execute the remining code.

Comment: I understand your point completly. is there any solution for this.
I want to stop my other methods before complete execution of asyncInterface.
All the other code depends up succes of async. for example LoginGui call Login class where there is async Call. on the success of the event next page is Loaded.I cant make object of another nextPage in Onsuccess method. As i want to seprate GUI and the Logical part.

Comment: Add a callback argument to your `setConnection` method to be called `onSuccess` (or, easier, pass an `AsyncCallback` to your method, that you pass directly to your RPC; or simply remove your `LoginServer` and use the `connectionService` directly).

Answer (score 1):

```
setConnectionnull
```

This is because the call back function is executed asynchronously. That is, this function is invoked after the response comes to the browser from the server. But the other part of the code like

```
 connection=loginServer.getConnection();
```

are executed immediately by which time connection is still null.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Hi NewCodeLearner, make the object of nextPage in the onSuccess. That is, do not initialize it before.

Comment: Ya but there are somePanels which need to be `setvisible(false);` Like THis `if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(connection)) { loginPanel.getParent().getParent().getParent() .setVisible(false);NexPage nexpage = new Nexpage(); `